# Why cant i use vector in scale fill manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I Want to create a graph that uses scale fill manual to fill colours of graph.

```
G3 <- ggplot(preTMM, aes(Var2, value, fill=group))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  Gtheme2+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("Log-CPM")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("pCDNA"="grey59","M"= "steelblue3"),
                    breaks=c("pCDNA","M"))+
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

This works fine, but if i want to add it via a vector that was made previously;

```
DGEGroup1 <- "pCDNA"
DGEGroup2 <- "M" 
DGEGroup1Col <- "grey59"
DGEGroup2Col <- "steelblue3"
```

it doesnt work.. what am I doing wrong.

```
G3 <- ggplot(preTMM, aes(Var2, value, fill=group))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  Gtheme2+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("Log-CPM")+
scale_fill_manual(values=c(DGEGroup1=DGEGroup1Col,DGEGroup2=DGEGroup1Col),
                    breaks=c(DGEGroup1,DGEGroup2))+
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

I want to do this so all the graphs can be controlled by one colour vector if that makes sense?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't supplied a reproducible example, but as Gregor Thomas points out, this just isn't how you create named vectors in R. Here's an example using the built-in `iris` dataset that shows how you could use your existing variables to get the intended results.

Firstly, I'll assign the group names and colour names to match your set-up:

```r
Group1 <- "setosa"
Group2 <- "versicolor"
Group3 <- "virginica"

Group1col  <- "red"
Group2col  <- "green"
Group3col  <- "blue"
```

To easily create a named vector, we can use `setNames`:

```
setNames(c(Group1col, Group2col, Group3col), c(Group1, Group2, Group3))
#>     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>      "red"    "green"     "blue"
```

So to use the named variables in your plot, you could do:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c(Group1col, Group2col, Group3col), 
                                       c(Group1, Group2, Group3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That syntax for a named vector doesn't work because R functions (including `c()`) don't require quotes for argument names:

```
x = "a"
y = "b"
c(x = y)
#   x 
# "b" 
## See how the name is literally `"x"`, not `"a"`
```

This is a Good Thing. It means that functions that have an argument named `x` don't break when you also have an object named `x`.

For your purpose, a good fix is to use `setNames` to name the vector. (You could also use `names(vector) <- ...` but `setNames` lets you keep it as a one-liner with an anonymous vector, much like you already have it).

```
values = setNames(
  c(DGEGroup1Col, DGEGroup2Col),
  nm = c(DGEGroup1, DGEGroup2)
)
```

However, if you're doing this for multiple plots I'd strongly suggest pulling out the definition of that vector earlier in you code so you're not repeating this syntax.